# Java EE duplicate info on same log line

Tags: java, wildfly, log4j2, java-ee-7, java-ee-8

I want to use log4j2 version 2.17.1 with wildfly 15. I did all that was written [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-log/how-to-use-log4j2-in-your-wildfly-applications/) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938432/logging-is-processed-by-the-logger-twice) but it isn't fully working.

My issue is that for the stdout logs, some information (like date and level) is duplicated on the same log line.

```
09:48:48,810 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2022-03-07 09:48:48,810 [default task-1] INFO  com.happypanda.rest.DashboardResourceImpl - Calling getDashboard with parameters: filter=null; order=null; offset=null; limit=null
```

I need only console logging. I tried to exclude the logging system but no success so far. I still see duplicates info on same line

standalone.xml configurations:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="log4j.configurationFile" value="${env.JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/log4j2.xml"/>
</system-properties>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
    <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
    <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.github.tennaito">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

log4j2.xml location is under /standalone/configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What are the correct locations for jboss-deployment-structure.xml file? I tried WEB-INF, META-INF and resources.

It's even possible to use log4j2 to log stdout in wildfly?

**Later edit:**

I added the following config to standalone.xml file:

```
<console-handler name="stdout" autoflush="true">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
<logger category="stdout" use-parent-handlers="false">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="stdout"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

I see the same duplicate information on the same log line.

Comment: Have a look at the last note on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784573/152794. You'll need to create a `stdout` logger in the configuration.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I added the configuration but the issue is still present

Comment: Are you adding that via CLI or the web console?

Comment: I've added them to the standalone.xml. In the end it worked. I needed to restart the server

Comment: It's best to use CLI or the web console so that you don't have to restart the server.